# How to get all the app users current location on map?

Tags: android, gps

I am making two apps. one which is for users which is simply doing work of getting user location. I have created app to get user location. now I want to make another app for admin which will get the location of all the users who have installed that app. Now the problem is how to distinguish users data while sending it to the server.

I don't want the user to sign up. just install the app and admin can view the user. I am thinking to make database if I will somehow be able to send some id with user's last location. If there's any alternative for this please suggest.

Comment: your question is too broad. In general, you need a server, which will accept the user locations from the user app, and will give all users' locations to the admin app. From here you can select whatever you want to implement it, as there are at least hundreds of ways how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android is for distinguish user.

import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```